# GoogleApiClient showing null pointer error

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to run a map app but there showing some error

Logcat:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tracker.systechdigital.realtimetrackingandmonitoring/com.tracker.systechdigital.realtimetrackingandmonitoring.NavigationDrawerActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.connect()' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2521)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2595)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5631)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
```

Gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.6.1'

}
```

Java:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation_drawer);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    context = NavigationDrawerActivity.this;

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    View hView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);


    ownProfilePic = (ImageView) hView.findViewById(R.id.ownImageShowDrawerHeaderIvId_navigationDrawer);
    ownNameShow = (TextView) hView.findViewById(R.id.showUserNameTvId_navigationDrawer);

    /******************************   own profile name and image show **************************  */


    ownNameShow.setText(UserInfo.getOwnProfileName());
    //        new ImageDownloaderTask(ownProfilePic).execute(UserInfo.ownProfilePicUrl);
    Picasso.with(context).load(UserInfo.getOwnProfilePicUrl()).resize(100, 100).placeholder(R.drawable.profile_show).error(R.drawable.profile_show).transform(new CircleTransform()).into(ownProfilePic);

    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        return;
    }
    this.lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    provider = lm.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    location = this.lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    this.locationListener = new NavigationDrawerActivity();
    this.lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 5, locationListener);


    if (location != null) {

        setUpMapIfNeeded(location);
        updateUserLatLong(location);

    }
    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    if (client == null)
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addConnectionCallbacks(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();

    //route
}

@Override

protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        return;

    }
    Location location = this.lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if (location != null) {
        setUpMapIfNeeded(location);
    }

}

public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    //        if(client!=null)
    client.connect();
    Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
            Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
            "Maps Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
            // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
            // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
            // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
            Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
            // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app deep link URI is correct.
            Uri.parse("android-app://com.tracker.systechdigital.realtimetrackingandmonitoring/http/host/path")
    );
    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, viewAction);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    this.mMap = googleMap;

    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        return;
    }
    Location location = this.lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    if (location != null) {
        setUpMapIfNeeded(location);

        UserInfo.setLat(location.getLatitude());
        UserInfo.setLng(location.getLongitude());
        UserInfo.setLocation(location);
    }
    //setUpMapIfNeeded(location);

    mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, Live_MapActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("Driver", "anyFriend");

            UserInfo.setFriendsId(friendIds.optString(marker.getId()));
            startActivity(intent);

            Toast.makeText(context, "You tracking " + marker.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    if (location != null && SharedPreference.getDefaults("ownUserId", context) != "0") {

        updateUserLatLong(location);
        //setUpMapIfNeeded(location);
        float speed = location.getSpeed();
        UserInfo.setSpeed(speed);

        UserInfo.setLat(location.getLatitude());
        UserInfo.setLng(location.getLongitude());
        UserInfo.setLocation(location);
    }
    userPosition = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),
            location.getLongitude());

    if (mMap != null) {
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(userPosition,
                12));
        mMap.setMapType(UserInfo.getMapType());
    }


    //updateUserLatLong(location);


    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)

    {

        return;
    }

    //        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    //        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);

    LatLng userPosition = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),
            location.getLongitude());

    if (mMap != null) {
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(userPosition,
                UserInfo.getZoomLevel()));

        mMap.setMapType(UserInfo.getMapType());

        userFriendsPos();

    }
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMapAsync(this);

        //            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
            Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
            "Maps Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
            // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,

            // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
            // Otherwise, set the URL to null.

            Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
            // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app deep link URI is correct.
            Uri.parse("android-app://com.tracker.systechdigital.realtimetrackingandmonitoring/http/host/path")
    );
    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, viewAction);
    client.disconnect();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

    Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
            Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
            "Maps Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
            // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
            // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
            // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
            Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
            // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app deep link URI is correct.
            Uri.parse("android-app://com.tracker.systechdigital.realtimetrackingandmonitoring/http/host/path")
    );
    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, viewAction);

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
            client);


}
```

can anyone please solve this. i can not find out the right things required there. i edited the question and added the oncreated method

Comment: Not clear! Post your error msg

Comment: I think `if(client!=null)` should be `if(client==null)`.

Comment: not solved with that @SuperThomasLab

Comment: @AAA post where you are calling connect()?

Comment: Can you post your full Java code?

Comment: Why you have commented if(client!=null) line in onStart()?

Comment: error showing in onstart client.connect

Comment: because it not solved my problem on AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, viewAction); this line @Raghavendra

Comment: better put the logs

Comment: @Shubham log is there please check

Answer (score 1):

Replace your onCreate method with the following code:

```
private static final int MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation_drawer);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    context = NavigationDrawerActivity.this;

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    View hView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);


    ownProfilePic = (ImageView) hView.findViewById(R.id.ownImageShowDrawerHeaderIvId_navigationDrawer);
    ownNameShow = (TextView) hView.findViewById(R.id.showUserNameTvId_navigationDrawer);

    /******************************   own profile name and image show **************************  */


    ownNameShow.setText(UserInfo.getOwnProfileName());
    //        new ImageDownloaderTask(ownProfilePic).execute(UserInfo.ownProfilePicUrl);
    Picasso.with(context).load(UserInfo.getOwnProfilePicUrl()).resize(100, 100).placeholder(R.drawable.profile_show).error(R.drawable.profile_show).transform(new CircleTransform()).into(ownProfilePic);

    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                new String[]{
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
                },
                MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE
        );
        return;
    } else {
        setupLocation();
    }

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    if (client == null)
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addApi(AppIndex.API)
                .build();

    //route
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED || grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                // TODO
                finish();
                return;
            }

            setupLocation();
            break;
    }
}

private void setupLocation() {
    this.lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    provider = lm.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    location = this.lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    this.locationListener = new NavigationDrawerActivity();
    this.lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 5, locationListener);


    if (location != null) {

        setUpMapIfNeeded(location);
        updateUserLatLong(location);

    }
}
```

Comment: @AAA Are you sure? Can you post you full java code, please?

Comment: @SuperThomasLab it looks pretty straight forward the error is in onStart -> client.connect(); line. client is null.

Comment: @Raghavendra just want to make sure.

Comment: @AAA nevermind, I had it wrong. Are you sure `client` is the same object in `onCreate()` and `onStart()`?

Comment: now showing error in this line 
location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                client);

Comment: @AAA OK could you please post your whole file? That would make it easier for us to help.

Comment: @SuperThomasLab wait it working now i edited the client req. i need to check more if it really working well or will show error again. you are really helpful.

Comment: how can i contact you if i face any problem in future? i am new to android so if you dont mind i want to connect with you

Comment: @AAA just ask a question on StackOverflow. Remember to post your log and code. Did you get it solved?

Comment: no again showing error :( @SuperThomasLab how to show you my code?

Comment: @AAA where is `client`?

Comment: i declar it in field level

Comment: @AAA https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: @SuperThomasLab i told you a new in android so if you please show where and how to edit the code please

Comment: i was seeing you code what this means?
MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE

Comment: @AAA it is used to identify the permission request.

Comment: @SuperThomasLab cannot resolve  MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE

Comment: Add `private static final int MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;` above your `onCreate()` method.

Comment: this time 
SecurityException: my location requires permission ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION or ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION error in OnMapReady

Comment: why this error showing now

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.getContext()' on a null object reference

Comment: @SuperThomasLab at last i have solved all error . thank you very much. you helped me alot